# symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

```
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    ld: warning: dylib (/Users/Shared/store/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/abseil/absl.framework/absl) was built for newer iOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.0)
    ld: warning: dylib (/Users/Shared/store/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/gRPC-C++/grpcpp.framework/grpcpp) was built for newer iOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.0)
    ld: warning: dylib (/Users/Shared/store/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/leveldb-library/leveldb.framework/leveldb) was built for newer iOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.0)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Encountered error while building for device.
```

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E266
> darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
> • Flutter version 2.0.0 at /Applications/flutter2.0_midhilaj
> • Framework revision 60bd88df91 (4 weeks ago), 2021-03-03 09:13:17 -0800
> • Engine revision 40441def69
> • Dart version 2.12.0
>
> [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 30.0.3)
> • Android SDK at /Users/midhilajm/Library/Android/sdk
> • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
> • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/midhilajm/Library/Android/sdk
> • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
> ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
>
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
> • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
> • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
> • CocoaPods version 1.10.1
>
> [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
> • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
> • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
> • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
> • Dart plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
> • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio 2.app/Contents
> • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
> • Dart plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
>
> [✓] VS Code (version 1.54.3)
> • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
> • Flutter extension can be installed from:
>  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
>
> [✓] Connected device (1 available)
> • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.90
> ! Error: Midhilaj’s iPhone is not connected. Xcode will continue when Midhilaj’s iPhone is connected. (code -13)
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `flutter upgrade` to upgrade to most recent version of Flutter. After that, `flutter clean` and build again. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Can you explain your answer, why does this fix the issue?

Comment: @mfleshman generally speaking, upgrading to latest version of the framework is the first thing you should try in case of any problems. From my experience, this solves more than half of the problems.

Comment: One of explanations for why this strategy works is an assumption that unexpected errors are caused by outter factors. For example, Apple may change something in iOS so that older flutter versions can't cope with the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing which solved me this problem is to clear the pub cache by deleting `pubspec.lock` file and re running `flutter run` command.

This mainly happens due to the error in the cached plugin files